# Flexible scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to add Scroll bars to div when window is minimized and remove when maximized i try to use this script but its not work

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
               var bodywidth = $(document).width();
               $("#tabMain").width(bodywidth);
           });
    </script>
```

here my div:

```
   <div class="tabsMainCont" id="tabMain">
          <ul class="tabsMenu">
          <li><a href="#" id="Profile">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="Clinics">My Clinics</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="Assistants">My Assistants</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="Mangment">Mangment</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tabsContent">
          <p>test</p>
          </div>
      </div>
```

and this the css i do so far:

```
.tabsMainCont 
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 19px;
    width: 1257px;
}

.tabsMenu
{
    float:left;
   overflow: hidden; margin: 0 0 0 0; background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f3f3f3 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#f3f3f3)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f3f3f3 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f3f3f3 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f3f3f3 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f3f3f3 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f3f3f3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
   border-bottom: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
   width:100%;
       -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
height:43px;
}

.tabsMenu li
{
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    border-right: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    height:43px;
width:340px;
}

.tabsMenu li a
{
padding:11px 26px 26px 118px;  
display:block;
color:Black;
}


.tabsMenu li a:hover
{
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #eaeaea 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#eaeaea)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#eaeaea 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#eaeaea 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#eaeaea 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#eaeaea 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eaeaea',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
color:Black;
}

.tabsMenu li a:focus
{
background: rgb(244,244,244); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(244,244,244,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(244,244,244,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(244,244,244,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(244,244,244,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(244,244,244,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(244,244,244,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f4f4f4', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.tabsMainCont .tabsContent
{
background-color:White;
border-radius:4px;
overflow:auto; 
float:left;
width:100%;   
}
```

the tabsContent div is that one i want it to scroll

Comment: And what is the problem? If I put your code (even without javascript) it works. How do you want the scroll to be? Horizontal or vertical?

Comment: i want my scroll to be both Horizontal and vertical and this css so far not make the scroll show when minimize

Comment: If you wish to have a vertical scroll as well you need to set a height for that `.tabsContent`

Comment: i give it height 100px and its same i didn't want the scroll is show when the content in this div stretch the height i give to it like the code area here no i want the scroll only show when minimize or maximize my screen like the body scroll so in low screen resolution user can move the scroll to see the rest of the  tabsContent content

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to use a horizontal and vertical scroll outside of what the browser gives you then you need to set the width and height of the element you want to scroll on (in this case `.tabsContent`) this can be px or % based. Given the fact you have already set `.tabsMenu` to have overflow hidden, then if you just add:

```
float: left;
overflow: auto;
```

to the `.tabsMainCont` element then that will scroll horizontally only when there is additional content in the `.tabsContent` element.

EDIT: the only problem i foresee with this is that the vertical scroll bar will be on right most edge of the `.tabsMainCont` which will cause you usability issues, that being the case I would strongly recommend only using overflow-x on the element and use the browsers vertical scroll, so updated css would be:

```
.tabsMainCont 
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 19px;
    width: 1257px;
    float:left;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```